# scientific notation and number sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Below snippet output the missing numbers in given sequence. It works fine for decimals but does not work with scientific notation (i.e. 1.6646144E7).
How to fix this?

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="OriginalSequence">16646145 1.6646144E7 16646149 1.6646148E7 16646151 1.664615E7 16646163 1.6646162E7</xsl:variable>        
    <!--<xsl:variable name="OriginalSequence">1 2 8 2 3</xsl:variable>-->
    <xsl:variable name="seq1" as="xs:integer*" select="for $s in $OriginalSequence/tokenize(normalize-space(.), '\s+') return xs:integer($s)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="seq2" as="xs:integer*"  select="min($seq1) to max($seq1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="seq3" as="xs:integer*" select="$seq2[not(. = $seq1)]"/>
    <missing><xsl:value-of select="$seq3"/></missing>       
</xsl:template>
```

Desired Ouput:

```
  <missing>16646145 16646146 16646147 16646152 16646153 16646154 16646155 16646156 16646157 16646158 16646159 16646160 16646161</missing>
```

The variable originalSequence is output of arithmetic operation in my original xslt, I am not sure if I can tell xslt2.0 that DO NOT convert to scientific notation?

Comment: What does your arithmetic operation compute, a sequence of `xs:integer`s? Or `xs:double`s? How does it look exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fix in your sample you can use `xs:integer(xs:double($s))` instead of the direct attempt `xs:integer($s)`. But if your real code first creates `xs:double`s instead of `xs:integer`s you might simply be able to change that code to create integers. It depends on the code you have and have not shared.

Comment: This is great :). Thanks, Martin!

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if I can tell xslt2.0 that DO NOT convert to scientific
>   notation?

Yes, you can use the format-number() function to get exactly the format you want. The default number-to-string conversion uses exponential notation for numbers outside the range 1e-6 to 1e+6.